# How to call Perl Script in Visual Studio with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, perl, visual-studio-2012

So currently I have a C#/ASP.net application in Visual Studio. I also have a perl script written by somebody else that I must use within my C#/ASP.NET application. The end goal is to pass a string generated within my C#/ASP.NET code into this perl script (the string is a file path) so that the perl script will run and give its appropriate output.

I've looked all over and only found this example:

```
ProcessStartInfo perlStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"d:\Perl\bin\perl.exe");
perlStartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\word-splitter.pl " + "c:\\a.txt" + " ispell";
perlStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
perlStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
perlStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

Process perl = new Process();
perl.StartInfo = perlStartInfo;
perl.Start();
perl.WaitForExit();
string output = perl.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Link is here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ea9455e1-b254-49e1-99df-41718ea80b5b/how-to-run-perl-scripts-in-c

The problem is that whenever I put this code into Visual Studio, it doesn't recognize ProcessStartInfo or any of the other namespaces that this code block uses. Am I missing an assembly?...also what exactly does this block even do? I've tried to search for Nuget packages and assemblies but only found PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions) which doesn't install because it's not compatible with .NetFramwork V4.5.

So my question is: what's the protocol for running a perl script inside of a C#/ASP.NET application?

Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify, you have included `using System.Diagnostics`, right?

Comment: I've just added it. The namespaces are recognized now. However I'm still quite unclear on where to go from here. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Check MSDN for classes you are using - there is a lot of information. Search for similar question on SO/everywhere... When you get past "please explain how `Process.Start` works" update the question so it become concrete problem suitable for SO. (Voting to close for now)

Answer (score 0):

You have the basic outline correct, so I won't bother trying to give you a step-by-step guide. Besides, I don't think I would be as helpful as [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.aspx). But, the main idea is that `ProcessStartInfo` is essentially used to set up all the properties needed to spawn of a separate process. Then, `Process` is used to actually start the process. `WaitForExit()` blocks your program from continuing until the spawned process completes.

However, some things I will say:

1. You are redirecting the standard output, but you don't appear to actually tell it where to go. Thus, trying to `ReadToEnd()` doesn't really have anywhere to read from...
2. Work on getting the process running first. Don't try to redirect the input/output or hide the window until you can spawn the process, see it work/give input directly to the terminal, and watch it exit. Incremental programming is your friend!
3. Read the documentation link. It's fairly straightforward, and provides good code examples. There are really only a handful of properties you will need to worry about, so don't get carried away trying to adjust every little thing at the moment.

Comment: Great thank you! I think I'll try to get a simple Hello World perl script running within C# while keeping in mind the things you've said. I appreciate your clear explanation!